# Write multiple time on TCP conn

Tags: go

I have a TCP server server :
`l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:"+strconv.Itoa(tcpPort))`

The server listens to incoming client requests as is :

```
    for {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        b := make([]byte, 1024)
        c.Read(b)
        fmt.Println(string(b)) // "Hello"
    }
```

I have a client :
`conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)`

Now I I write once with `conn.Write([]byte("Hello"))`

The server catches Hello. But if I have these :

```
_, err := conn.Write([]byte("Hello"))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

_, err = conn.Write([]byte("World"))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Then I will get `Hello`, but not `World`.

How can I write multiple time on the same connection ?

**Full function below**

```
func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer l.Close()

    go func() {
        for {
            c, err := l.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            b := make([]byte, 1024)
            c.Read(b)
            fmt.Println(string(b))
        }

    }()

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = conn.Write([]byte("world"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the server code, the one that receives data. It only reads once from the tcp stream. If you want it to read `"world"`, replace the single `read` operation by a loop:

```
go func() {
    for {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for {
            b := make([]byte, 1024)
            c.Read(b)
            fmt.Println(string(b))
      }
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with `conn.Write` but with reading from connection. Now you read just once from every new opened connection accepted by `l.Accept()`. Solution is to read repeatedly.

Your code is also limited to handle just one connection. And do not forget to check error from `c.Read(b)` to know when stop listen on this connection.

```golang
go func() {
    for {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go func(conn net.Conn) {
            for {
                b := make([]byte, 1024)
                _, err := conn.Read(b)
                if err != nil {
                    if err != io.EOF {
                        fmt.Println("read error:", err)
                    }
                    break
                }
                fmt.Println(string(b))
            }
            fmt.Println("Stopping handle connection")
        }(c)
    }
}()
```